Firestore PHP Client permission denied
I want to use Google's Firestore to save user data, while the backend uses PHP. So far I configured the access rules like this:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

I followed google's official documentation and my code looks like this:
$firestore = new FirestoreClient([
  'projectId' => env('firebase.project.id'),
  'keyfileName' => env('firebase.key.file')
]);

$collection = $firestore->collection('users');
$document = $collection->document($uid);

//this one triggers the permission error
$secret_key = $document->snaphot->get('secret_key');

Then I get:
PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

I tried to modify my rules like this:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}

No difference. By the way, the firebase authentication part works, I can create users and make them logged in. Furthermore, if I turn of the rules the error vanishes, but obviosly that is not a solution. I'm using CodeIgniter 4.5.5 with the most recent google/cloud-firestore. When I will be back in my office, I can link all the dependencies. For now, I would appreciate any help.

The PHP SDK for Firestore is an Admin SDK, which means that you initialize it with administrative credentials and it then bypasses the security rules. So your security rules don't cause this message. More likely either the service account (file) wasn't picked up by your code, or it is missing a required permission/role. Unfortunately the error message is not very helpful. :(

Tomorrow I will paste the entire trace. Thank you for the instruction.

Finally here is the solution.
I used kreait/firebase-php implementation of firestore. However make sure you fulfill all requirements listed in google's doc to make it work.
Dependencies in composer.json:
"firebase/php-jwt": "^6.10",
"google/cloud-firestore": "^1.47",
"google/gax": "1.35.1",
"google/protobuf": "^4.29",
"grpc/grpc": "^1.57",
"kreait/firebase-php": "^7.0"

Firestore:
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\DocumentSnapshot;
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
use Kreait\Firebase\Contract\Auth;
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

...
 
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->factory =  (new Factory())
            ->withServiceAccount(env('firebase.key.file'))
            ->withFirestoreDatabase('(default)');
 
        $this->auth = $this->factory->createAuth();

        //this one gives the FirestoreClient
        $this->firestore = $this->factory->createFirestore()->database();
    }

   ...
 
    public function getUserData(string $uid) : DocumentSnapshot
    {
        $collection = $this->firestore->collection('users');
        $user = $collection->document($uid);
        return $user->snapshot();
    }

    public function saveUserData(string $uid, array $data) : void
    {
        $collection = $this->firestore->collection('users');
        $user = $collection->document($uid);
        $user->set($data);
    }


I don't know if the typo is in your actual code, but I'm pretty sure that it should be $secret_key = $document->snapshot->get('secret_key');, not $document->snaphot.
